# Emerson QP+ 7" don't communicate with Micrologix 1500

Tags: panel, plc

I have a Micrologix 1500 connected to a 1761-NET-AIC with a 1761-CBL-HM02 cable.
This is then connected to a 1747-AIC which is then connected in parallel with other PLCs. From J2 port on the 1747-AIC, I had an old Emerson 6" IC745VSB06MTD-LH connected with a HMI-CAB-74/F cable.
The Emerson panel was configured as DH485.
The panel died and bought a brand new QP+ 7" IC755CSW07CDA-AEBA, downloaded the same program, and tried using a 2711C-CBL-AB03 to connect from the 1747-AIC RJ45 port to the HMI 5 pin serial port but i am not getting any signals.

I also tried using an HMI-CBL-C52 cable to connect the HMI directly to the NET-AIC but still no luck. Any ideas?

The panel died and bought a brand new QP+ 7" IC755CSW07CDA-AEBA, downloaded the same program, and tried using a 2711C-CBL-AB03 to connect from the 1747-AIC RJ45 port to the HMI 5 pin serial port but i am not getting any signals.

I also tried using an HMI-CBL-C52 cable to connect the HMI directly to the NET-AIC but still no luck. Any ideas?